# Android webview ':active' stays on when elem is hidden while it is active

Tags: css

I'm building a html-app for Android and I have an issue with the :active css rule. It works like it should BUT when I hide an element that is ':active'. the state is never dismissed.

For example:
I have a button with this css:

```
.button:active { background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5); }
```

and this javascript:

```
$(".button").on("click",function(evt){ 
    $(evt.originalEvent.target).css("display","none"); 
});
```

When I tap the button it is hidden. But when I un-hide it, it will still have the .button:active css rule applied.

Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got it working with a MAJOR workaround (because event.target for touches returns the element the user tapped on which may very well be a childnode of the actual element that binds the events (see example below, it will return the [img] elem, not the [div]). Seufs.

PS: @Richa's answer did help me to do a workaround instead of hoping there would be a fix for :active

**HTML (snippet)**

```
<div class='button activatablel'><img src='someicon.png'></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.activatablel { /* nothing, just used to find the elements with jquery) */ }

.activatablel_active {
    background:#f00;
}
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
elems = $(".activatablel");

for (var i in elems) {
    var elem = elems[i];
    elem.ontouchstart = function(evt) {
        // Now we have to find the ACTUAL element that bound this event 
        // because somebody decided it's useful to not do this &$*((@^#))_
        var foundTheActualTarget = false;
        var thetarget = evt.target;
        var whilenum = 0;
        while (!foundTheActualTarget) {
            if (thetarget.className) {
                if (thetarget.className.indexOf("activatablel")>=0) {
                    foundTheActualTarget = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            thetarget = thetarget.parentNode;
            whilenum++;
            if (whilenum>256) { break; } // TODO: unless we intend to do this job in Reno, we're in Barney
        }
        if ($(thetarget).hasClass("activatablel_active")) { return; }
        $(thetarget).addClass("activatablel_active");
    }
    elem.ontouchend = function(evt) {
        $("*").removeClass("activatablel_active");
    }
    elem.ontouchcancel = elem.ontouchend;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
$(".button").on("click",function(evt){ 
    $(evt.originalEvent.target).removeClass("active");/*Or whatever your class name is**/
    $(evt.originalEvent.target).css("display","none"); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately I'm not using a class, I'm using the :active selector (not the ':', it works like :hover and such) which should be true while ontouch and false ontouchend.
:active selector http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_active.asp